# How to format $.now() with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format

`$.now()` gives me the time as miliseconds. I need to show it something like `hh:mm:ss`

How can I do that in Jquery?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
function formatTimeOfDay(millisSinceEpoch) {
  var secondsSinceEpoch = (millisSinceEpoch / 1000) | 0;
  var secondsInDay = ((secondsSinceEpoch % 86400) + 86400) % 86400;
  var seconds = secondsInDay % 60;
  var minutes = ((secondsInDay / 60) | 0) % 60;
  var hours = (secondsInDay / 3600) | 0;
  return hours + (minutes < 10 ? ":0" : ":")
      + minutes + (seconds < 10 ? ":0" : ":")
      + seconds;
}
```

Comment: +1 , for covering all use cases and nice usage of conditional operators

Comment: @Barış V.: Note that this has nothing to do with jQuery. (Nor does it need to.)

Comment: What about daylight saving time? Considering that all days have 24 hours is wrong, and this function will lead to incorrect times.

Comment: this is pretty complex for something so simple don't you think? I just wish there was an easier way.

Comment: @Gabriel, you can combine my approach to get the formatting right with Vinod's use of the get methods thus: `var hours = d.getHours(), minutes = d.getMinutes(), seconds = d.getSeconds(); return hours + (minutes < 10 ? ":0" : ":") + minutes ...`

Comment: JB Nizet, that is correct.  If you know the timezone offset, you can just add timezoneOffsetInMinutes * 60 to secondsSinceEpoch.  If you want to use the local timezone, that offset is available obliquely via the `Date` API.  Otherwise, you really have to define a timezone which can be a hard task.  RFC 5545 comes up with a definition based on recurrences which satisfies its need to allow reproducible timezone definitions.

Answer (score 39):

I'd suggest just using the Javascript Date object for this purpose.

```
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
```

Edit: I just came across the method below, which covers formatting issues such as the one mike-samuel mentioned and is cleaner:

```
    var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
```

Comment: Nice, but if the time is 1AM you will get `1:0:0` instead of `1:00:00`.

Comment: @vinod +1 nice and simple answer.

Answer (score 4):

JSFiddle example here

http://jsfiddle.net/NHhMv/

The jquery now is nothing but

The $.now() method is a shorthand for the number returned by the expression

```
(new Date).getTime().
```

from jquery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/

and follow this link

[Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

```
new Date().toString().split(' ')[4]
```

or

```
new Date().toString().match(/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/)[0]
```

The `toString` method is basically an alias for `toLocaleString` in most implementations. This will return the time in the user's timezone as opposed to assuming UTC by using milliseconds if you use `getTime` (if you use `getMilliseconds` you should be OK) or `toUTCString`.

Comment: With this getting exact difference in time is as simple as ever: `(new Date(new Date(string) - new Date())).toUTCString().split(' ')[4]`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest date-format jQuery plugin. Like [this one](http://www.timdown.co.uk/code/simpledateformat.php) or [this one](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) (I am using the former)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't have date formatting. You can roll your own with the JavaScript `Date` object, or you can use a library that does it for you. [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/) is one such library, which provides a rich set of formatting, parsing, and manipulation functionality. However, it hasn't been maintained in years. `momentjs` is under active development.

Comment: Datepicker does not handle time!

Answer (score 1):

I'm way late to this, but thought i'd just throw this little snippet out there for the masses. This is something I use just to get a quick localized timestamp. It's pretty clean and handy.

```
function getStamp() {
    var d = new Date();

    var mm = d.getMilliseconds(), hh = d.getHours(),
        MM = d.getMinutes(), ss = d.getSeconds();

    return (hh < 10 ? "0" : "") + hh + (MM < 10 ? ":0" : ":") + MM + (ss < 10 ? ":0" : ":") + ss + ":" + mm;
};
```